# How can I see daily charges in the new administrative Dashboard

Tags: google-app-engine

In the old UI this was possible from the "Usage History" link. In the new UI I can only see monthly totals in history but I might have missed the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is now under Quotas/Usage History

Just update the url below with your project id. Then click at "view usage history".

https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/quotadetails/history?project=PROJECT_ID

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12414153)

Comment: @AnirudhSharma In this rare case, a link-only answer is the right kind of answer (read the question)